# How to find the least possible capturing group in OR list regex

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

I want to capture the words after `me_start:` pattern with the following with regular expression `me_start: ([\s\S]{1,})(?:end_1|end_2|end3)` and till any of the described words in this OR list will be found. But it works in other way and capture the longest possible group.

**Example:**

`me_start: cat end_1 dog end_2`
in this sentence I want to capture `cat` word, but it catches `cat end_1 dog` words. 
How to make it in the way I need

Comment: BTW: `\S=[^\s]` so `[\s\S]` matches *everything* like `.` with `re.DOTALL`... are you sure you want that? IMHO It's clearer to just use `.` with `re.DOTALL` if you want to say "match everything".

Answer (score 3):

Change the `{1,}` greedy quantifier to the non-greedy version `{1,}?`:

```
>>> re.match(r'me_start: ([\s\S]{1,}?)(?:end_1|end_2|end3)', 'me_start: cat end_1 dog end_2').groups()
('cat ',)
```

From the [`re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> Causes the resulting RE to match from m to n repetitions of the
>   preceding RE, attempting to match as few repetitions as possible. This
>   is the non-greedy version of the previous qualifier. For example, on
>   the 6-character string 'aaaaaa', a{3,5} will match 5 'a' characters,
>   while a{3,5}? will only match 3 characters.